# How to solve SQL Error: ORA-01858 in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, create-table, ora-01858

I am trying to create a table with an existing DDL file, the statement is pretty much like this

```
CREATE TABLE SYSTEM.LS_Ss_VERSION 
    ( 
     ID NUMBER (20)  NOT NULL , 
     SSID NUMBER (20) , 
     CONTENT VARCHAR2 (4000 BYTE) , 
     CREATEDBY NUMBER (20) , 
     CREATED_ON DATE DEFAULT 'NULL' 
    )
```

The error am getting is

```
SQL Error: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
*Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
           incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
           required by the format model.
```

I have searched google, but couldnt get proper solution.. Plese suggest me a solution here.

Comment: **Do not create tables in the SYSTEM schema.**  This is an special account provided by Oracle to do background tasks.  You risk corrupting your database by changing its schema.

Answer (score 4):

Please remove 'NULL' to null and try in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/256ab and test it :

```
CREATE TABLE LS_Ss_VERSION 
    ( 
     ID NUMBER (20)  NOT NULL , 
     SSID NUMBER (20) , 
     CONTENT VARCHAR2 (4000 BYTE) , 
     CREATEDBY NUMBER (20) , 
     CREATED_ON DATE DEFAULT NULL 
    )
```

Comment: What's problem in solution, is worked in oracle , you can also check in sqlfeddo

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this:

```
CREATED_ON DATE DEFAULT 'NULL'
```

`'NULL'` is a *string* so the database interprets that as  an implicit data conversion using whatever mask is specified as the default, such as `to_date('NULL', 'DD-MON-YYYY')`, which is clearly nonsense.

If we don't specify a value when populating a row the system puts in NULL (not a string) so we don't need to specify this ...

```
CREATED_ON DATE DEFAULT NULL
```

... as that's what happens anyway.  But given the column's name it would make more sense to specify:

```
CREATED_ON DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
```

Comment: `nls_date_format` session parameter value is taken instead of `dd-mon-yyyy`, to be absolutely precise :)